# Elasticsearch.Net calculate custom document item score with NEST

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest, scoring

I have an issue for your help. My customer source on document has `unitid` field. I want to list current unit customer as first. So I try to use script scoring but all document item score calculated as 0, it was never worked. After successful scoring I wil sort result by score.

This is my script on filter;

```
.ScriptScore(s => s
    .Script(ss => ss
        .Source($"doc['unitid'].value == params.unitid ? _score = 1 : _score = 0")
        .Params(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "unitid", filter.UnitId } })
    )
)
```

And then this is my all query;

```
.Query(q => q
.Bool(b => b
    .Filter(m => m
        .Prefix(t => t.CustomerName, filter.CustomerName?.ToUpper()) && m
        .Terms(t => t
            .Field(f => f.CustomerTypeId)
            .Terms(new List<int> { 2, 3 })
        ) && m
        .ScriptScore(s => s
            .Script(ss => ss
                .Source($"doc['unitid'].value == params.unitid ? _score = 1 : _score = 0")
                .Params(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "unitid", 272 } })
            )
        )
    )
))
.Aggregations(a => a
    .Terms("distinct_accounts", c => c
        .Field(x => x.AccountId
            .Suffix("keyword")
        )
    ))
.Sort(s => s
    .Descending("_score")
    .Descending(a => a.ModifyDate));
```

As a result, where am I doing wrong, could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The script score query's source script needs to return the score value, rather than assigning it to some variable like `_score`

```cs
.ScriptScore(s => s
    .Script(ss => ss
        .Source($"doc['unitid'].value == params.unitid ? 1 : 0")
        .Params(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "unitid", filter.UnitId } })
    )
)
```

**EDIT:**

Just noticed that the script score query does not have a `.Query()` part, but it needs one to be a fully formed query. In addition, the queries are [inside a bool query filter clause, meaning that scoring is ignored](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#score-bool-filter).

Thinking more about the underlying problem you're trying to solve , giving certain documents a higher score than others is typically achieved by boosting the scores for a certain query. For example

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var filter = new 
{
    CustomerName = "foo",
    UnitId = 1
};

var response = client.Search<Product>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(s => s
                .Term(t => t
                    .Boost(10)
                    .Field("unitid")
                    .Value(filter.UnitId)
                )
            )
            .Filter(fi => fi
                .Prefix(t => t.CustomerName, filter.CustomerName?.ToUpper()), 
                    fi => fi
                .Terms(t => t
                    .Field(f => f.CustomerTypeId)
                    .Terms(new List<int> { 2, 3 })
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("distinct_accounts", c => c
            .Field(x => x.AccountId
                .Suffix("keyword")
            )
        )
    )
    .Sort(s => s
        .Descending("_score")
        .Descending(a => a.ModifyDate)
    )
);
```

which yields the query

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_accounts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "accountId.keyword"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [{
          "prefix": {
            "customerName": {
              "value": "FOO"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "customerTypeId": [
              2,
              3
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [{
        "term": {
          "unitid": {
            "value": 1,
            "boost": 10.0
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  "sort": [{
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "modifyDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here, if a document has a `unitid` value of 1, then the score for this is boosted tenfold. I don't think the boost is actually needed here though anyway, as documents that don't have a `unitid` value of 1 will not have a score, and the other queries are in a filter score so won't contribute to the score. With the term query on `unitid` inside a `should` clause with the presence of `filter` clauses, this query acts as a boosting signal in that documents do not need to match this query to be returned, but if they do, the score from the `should` clause will be added to scores from other queries to form an overall score, which I think will achieve what you want.

Comment: @Waayd added some additional details.